# Ubuntu Live USB deletes folders on boot

Tags: uefi, live-usb

Pretty much first time user of Ubuntu here.
So I downloaded the ISO (file name ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) and also Rufus 3.4. I then wrote the ISO to a 64GB micro SD card through Rufus.
[Rufus settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFXCz.png) When I restarted to try and boot into Ubuntu, I do not see an option in the boot device selection to boot from the USB. On further investigation, some folders that had files in them after Rufus finished are now empty. The dists, EFI, install, isolinux, pics, pool and preseed folders are now empty.
I've tried setting the partition scheme between GPT and MBR. Also tried both DD and ISO image modes, and turning off secure boot.
Any solutions?

Comment: Use etcher to prepare that installer!